# Jquery UI Draggable Absolute Instead of Relative?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a div containing a few jquery draggables, however if at any point I remove one of these draggables from the page then this can move the rest of them as they are positioned with relative.

Here is a fiddle showcasing this:
http://jsfiddle.net/VolatileStorm/aNk6e/

My proposed solution is that the draggable should be using absolute as opposed to relative positioning, however I can't find a way to do this. Is there a way to do this, and if not, can anyone think of a way around it? (For elegance's sake, I won't accept "don't delete the other draggable").

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why doesn't [`position:absolute`](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/tgzRJ/) work for you?

Since absolutely positioned elements are no longer part of the document flow, each of your three `<div>`s are placed at `0,0` of its containing (positioned) element.  Thus, it's up to you to [work out the starting position of your draggables](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/EZweB/).

Comment: @VolatileStorm: No, it does not.  Check out my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/EZweB/) using `position:absolute` -- it's never changed to `relative`.

Comment: Yes. That's why I deleted the comment. It is in my "production code" so to speak. But wasn't in yours. However. If I set the position to absolute after I make it draggable then it stays absolute.

I guess I should've just pushed harder, haha. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify the scenario, if you set the position of draggable elements via css/inline to `absolute` then the draggable plugin doesn't set it for you inline to `relative`, and you can determine (or not) the starting position (helpful for dynamically-generated elements).  However, don't target `.ui-draggable` via css, as this selector seems to be added after it decides whether to apply positioning.

Comment: Another thing to add: This makes the parent-container stop scrolling, when it is set to `position:static`. To reenable scrolling, simply set it to `position:absolute`

Comment: note that if he is using parameter iframeFix: true, then jquery UI will convert it to relative positioning

Comment: This accepted solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643075/jquery-draggables-removing-an-element-changes-position-of-other-dropped-element solves a very similar problem.

Answer (score 22):

1. Add `position:absolute` to your elements.
2. Attach them to the DOM ***before*** calling `.draggable`.

Comment: that **before** saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You can set the position to be absolute by using the jQuery css function when setting an element to be draggable.

```
$(this).draggable().css("position", "absolute");
```

Comment: after setting position to absolute it can`t be dragged any more

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best ideas but... You could position all the relevant divs using positon:relative; and then include a function call in your  or $("document").ready(), if you're using jQuery, whic iterates through each of the divs to translate their relative positions into absolute and set them as their left, top before changing them to position:absolute. Only problem here is that you'd want each divs absolute position prior to updating their styles so as not to alter the layout through iteration.