# jQueryUI: properly removing a draggable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a visual editor that requires elements the user can add, remove, and drag around as they like. Each element is a `div` made draggable with jQueryUI. New elements are appended to a parent `div` that represents the workspace. Each element has a button inside itself to remove it. This all works great.

The problem I'm having is that when I remove an element that was not the most recently created, all the other draggable elements change position. This seems to be caused by the draggable elements using `relative` positioning.

At the moment, my removal function simply calls `$('#item-x').remove()`. Is there another way I should be removing draggable elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904531/jquery-ui-draggable-absolute-instead-of-relative), but I was searching for the wrong thing.

The solution is to simply change the elements to have absolute positioning, as per the other question. I found, however, that my elements would always revert to relative positioning even when I specified in their CSS that they should be absolute, so now I do:

```
$('#item-x').draggable().css("position", "absolute");
```

Comment: As per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22432224/471441, it suffices to make sure you add them to the DOM before calling `draggable`.

Answer (score 8):

Try using `.draggable("destroy")` instead. I have used it just fine.

You can view this method and all other methods, options and events at [jqueryUI Draggable destroy](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#method-destroy)

**Update**

Sorry i thought your problem was something else. What you need to do is change your approach, because removing the element from dom has actually nothing to do with an element being `draggable`. You need to put encapsulate your draggable with an element for example a div with the same height and width than your draggable, then just destroy the draggable as you please.

HTML:

```
<div id="conteiner">
   <div class="dragConteiner"><div id="draggable1" class="draggable"></div></div>
   <div class="dragConteiner"><div id="draggable2" class="draggable"></div></div>
   <div class="dragConteiner"><div id="draggable3" class="draggable"></div></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

  $("#draggable1").draggable();
  $("#draggable2").draggable();
  $("#draggable3").draggable();
  $("#draggable2").on('mouseup',function(){
    alert('bye draggable!');
    $(this).draggable('destroy');
    //in case you like to use if after
    //$(this).hide();
    //as in your code
    $(this).remove();
  })
})
```

CSS:

```
.draggable{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background: green;    
}

.dragConteiner{
   height:50px;
   width:50px;
   margin-top:5px;    
}

#conteiner{
   margin-top:25px;
   margin-left:25px;
}
```

​
​A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tHZTM/6/) example

Comment: For me, "deatroy" ends up having the same effect as "disable" - i.e., the element stops being draggable, but stays in the same position. Could I be doing something wrong when _creating_ the elements?

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster see my update and tell me if it helped you out.

Comment: Fair enough solution, but since I'm writing an editor, I'd end up with a ton of empty containers where people have added nodes then removed them.

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons destroy function is not working. If you want to completely remove the drag property from the element try this

```
var temp = $("#dragItem").draggable().remove();
```

This returns the element by removing the draggable property. Capture in a temp variable and assign it back to the parent element

```
$(temp).appendTo("#parentContainer")
```

Let me know if this works.