# Removing jQuery UI sortable and draggable classes completely

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a sortable which also contains draggables. I'd like to completely remove all the additional code that `.sortable` and `.draggable` adds to my html (additional classes and inline styles). If I use `draggable('disable')` and `sortable('disable')` it doesn't remove the classes but adds a `ui-sortable-disabled` class which makes things worse!

I'm essentially trying to clean the sortable html so it can be exported, is this possible?

**UPDATE: This question has __NOTHING__ to do with the "duplicate" that is linked above. Someone obviously is eager for those points! The first answer at the top of the page states: "Sorry i thought your problem was something else..." and the question is about removing elements.** And yes, I did search, hence the question, "dude". It's ok. I won't expect an apology, I forgive you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQueryUI: properly removing a draggable element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452677/jqueryui-properly-removing-a-draggable-element)

Comment: Please don't tell me you didn't see this question with same answer. It's on top of google results for the same title

Comment: I didn't want to remove a draggable element - that would be `.remove`. I wanted to remove the draggable functionality. Please...don't tell me you didn't see that.

Comment: Dude, the first line of top voted answer answers your question... rest is just specific to the OP which anyone can ignore if not applicable to them. The point is, googling the same title brings up that answer on top. It is evident that you haven't done any research

Comment: duuuudeeee... you're so angry, chill. Also, the question you think is a duplicate is nothing to do with this question. If you don't understand why then not to worry.

Answer (score 0):

so, the answer is not to use `disable` but `destroy`. So, `$('#someid').sortable('destroy')`. This also works for draggable